# TypeError: botconfig.findServiceByNameOrId(...).getEndpoint is not a function

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Endpoint:

```
(<LuisService>botconfig.findServiceByNameOrId("aiBot")).getEndpoint()
```

In here when I debugging I am getting an error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: Ideally, use paragraphs for your questions, avoid txtspk and slang, and add as much detail as you can.

Comment: There are a lot of things that could possibly be going wrong here. Is the bot file being read correctly? Is the bot configuration successfully stored in `botConfig`? Is aiBot an actual LUIS service in your bot file? Is the service being cast to `LuisService` successfully? Is the `LuisService` type imported into your module successfully? Please do some further testing to find out what's actually going wrong, and provide us with your code so that we can actually help.